# Load time tool report shows chains of weird redirects

Tags: redirect, malware

These are the redirects reported for my WordPress site:

```
Remove the following redirect chain if possible:
https://p.nexac.com/e/sr/a-1549/s-3261/s-3261.xgi?33random=1522296920667
https://p.nexac.com/e/sr/a-1549/s-3261/s-3261.xgi?33random=1522296920667&rd=Y
https://e.dlx.addthis.com/e/sr/a-1549/s-3261/s96920667&rd=Y&na_id=2018032904152132070070257380
https://stags.bluekai.com/site/1407?partner=1&uac.com%2Fe%2Fbk_sync.xgi%3Fna_exid%3D%24_BK_UUID
https://e.nexac.com/e/bk_sync.xgi?na_exid=7ksemxOr999ZqqhS
https://x.dlx.addthis.com/e/bk_sync.xgi?na_exid=7ksemxOr999ZqqhS

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:
https://pixel.tapad.com/idsync/ex/receivepartn_DEVICE_ID%7D&partner_device_id=fZsemUOK99OVUqhS
https://match.adsrvr.org/track/cmf/generic?ttd_ ... %253Fid%253Dcc380091-3307-11e8-94ce-0242ac110004
https://match.adsrvr.org/track/cmb/generic?ttd_%253Fid%253Dcc380091-3307-11e8-94ce-0242ac110004
https://pixel.tapad.com/idsync/ex/receive?partn3583%3Fid%3Dcc380091-3307-11e8-94ce-0242ac110004
https://stags.bluekai.com/site/13583?id=cc380091-3307-11e8-94ce-0242ac110004

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:
https://rc.rlcdn.com/361726.gif?n=1&33random=1522295145022
https://rc.rlcdn.com/1000.gif?memo=CP6JFhoNCOnC8dUFEgUI6AcQAA
https://match.adsrvr.org/track/cmf/generic?ttd_pid=liveramp
https://match.adsrvr.org/track/cmb/generic?ttd_pid=liveramp
https://idsync.rlcdn.com/362588.gif?partner_uid=0b7cd08b-f18f-4491-8412-7e82cf42358e

Remove the following redirect chain if possible: 
https://match.adsrvr.org/track/cmf/generic?ttd_pid=bluekai
https://tags.bluekai.com/site/5386?id=0b7cd08b-f18f-4491-8412-7e82cf42358e
https://bluekai2waycm.netmng.com/cm/?
https://tags.bluekai.com/site/13209?id=mmi4yzmzywrjn

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:
https://cm.g.doubleclick.net/pixel?google_nid=bluekai&google_cm&google_sc
https://cm.g.doubleclick.net/pixel?google_nid=bluekai&google_cm=&google_sc=&google_tc=
https://tags.bluekai.com/site/2981?id=&google_gid=CAESEBaR2XdxDWhLbZXHhex0Tp4&google_cver=1

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:
https://ib.adnxs.com/getuid?https%3A%2F%2Fs.cpxpng%3Fref%3D%26pid%3D11657%26adnxs_uid%3D%24UID
https://ib.adnxs.com/bounce?%2Fgetuid%3Fhttps%2 ... 53D%2526pid%253D11657%2526adnxs_uid%253D%2524UID
https://s.cpx.to/ca.png?ref=&pid=11657&adnxs_uid=581660131562266600

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:
https://pixel.advertising.com/ups/19350/sync?uid=QEkfBykb9994znhS&_origin=1&redir=true
https://pixel.advertising.com/ups/19350/sync?uid=QEkfBykb9994znhS&_origin=1&redir=true&verify=true
https://tags.bluekai.com/site/4470?limit=0&id=UPa8bb852a-3303-11e8-af6c-069af4b4889c

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:
https://sync-tm.everesttech.net/upi/pid/2j4ke5f ... om%2Fsite%2F4413%3Fid%3D%24%7BUSER_ID%7D%26r=123
https://sync-tm.everesttech.net/ct/upi/pid/2j4k ... D%24%7BUSER_ID%7D%26r=123&_test=WrxhaQAAAH_fm3A-
https://tags.bluekai.com/site/4413?id=WrxhaQAAAH_fm3A-&r=123&_test=WrxhaQAAAH_fm3A-

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:
https://sync.mathtag.com/sync/img?mt_exid=10002 ... s.bluekai.com%2Fsite%2F4448%3Fid%3D%5BMM_UUID%5D
https://sync.mathtag.com/sync/img?mt_exid=10002 ... 2Fsite%2F4448%3Fid%3D%5BMM_UUID%5D&mm_bnc&mm_bct
https://stags.bluekai.com/site/4448?id=037c5abc-58f1-4100-81b8-984d82f13268

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:
https://www.google-analytics.com/r/collect?v=1& ... 442-2&_gid=584848645.1522295144&_r=1&z=849091417
https://stats.g.doubleclick.net/r/collect?v=1&a ... 45.1522295144&gjid=1682013582&_v=j66&z=849091417
https://www.google.com/ads/ga-audiences?v=1&aip ... 440.1522295144&jid=1525173074&_v=j66&z=849091417

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:
https://bcp.crwdcntrl.net/5/c=508/rand=1522295145022/pv=y/genp=IAB+Category_

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:
https://ib.adnxs.com/getuid?https://stags.bluekai.com/site/3085?id=
https://stags.bluekai.com/site/3085?id=

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:
https://idsync.rlcdn.com/405716.gif?partner_uid=CmUMK1q8YWgCTASAxDhjAg%3D%3D
https://idsync.rlcdn.com/405716.gif? 
partner_uid=CmUMK1q8YWgCTASAxDhjAg%3D%3D&redirect=1
```

The list goes on even longer but I will spare you. Is this the result of some kind of malware? These didn't show up last time I ran a check on my site. The only plugin I have installed since then is the analytics plugin - Google Analytics Dashboard for WP (GADWP)

How do I get rid of all that stuff, guys? I'm reaching new levels of desperation here.